# Burstly OAIAutoRefreshManager showing interstitials without the app requesting for them

Tags: ios, interstitial, millennial-media, burstly

We have a weird issue where the burstly interstitial ads keep popping up randomly without our app requesting them. We're using the Burstly SDK for iOS.

Looking at the burstly logs, it shows something like

```
[;2013-11-06 16:01:13.209 MyMusicApp[43490:a0b] [Burstly]d t=2571i, m=0x19365210, Refresh ad operation is requested.
2013-11-06 16:01:13.210 MyMusicApp[43490:a0b] [Burstly]d t=2571i, m=0x19365210, Will show prefetched ad.
2013-11-06 16:01:13.210 MyMusicApp[43490:a0b] [Burstly]d t=2571i, Reachability Flag     Status: -R -----l- networkStatusForFlags
2013-11-06 16:01:13.211 MyMusicApp[43490:a0b] [Burstly]d t=2571i, m=0x19365210,   NetworkController=0x13a6cdb0, NetworkName=millennial, Show of a prefetched ad is requested.
2013-11-06 16:01:13.211 MyMusicApp[43490:a0b] [Burstly]d t=2571i, m=0x19365210,   NetworkController=0x13a72c70, NetworkName=millennial, Received ad. Transferring to main   thread...
2013-11-06 16:01:13.211 MyMusicApp[43490:a0b] [Burstly]d t=2571i, m=0x19365210, NetworkController=0x13a72c70, NetworkName=millennial, Received ad on main thread. 
2013-11-06 16:01:13.211 MyMusicApp[43490:a0b] [Burstly]d t=2571i, m=0x19365210, Ad manager has received millennial ad.
2013-11-06 16:01:13.212 MyMusicApp[43490:a0b] [Burstly]d t=2571i, m=0x19365210, AutoRefreshManager=0x19ef45b0, Timer is stopped.
2013-11-06 16:01:13.212 MyMusicApp[43490:a0b] [Burstly]d t=2571i, m=0x19365210, AutoRefreshManager=0x19ef45b0, Current network is set to millennial.
2013-11-06 16:01:13.212 MyMusicApp[43490:a0b] [Burstly]d t=2571i, m=0x19365210, AutoRefreshManager=0x19ef45b0, Timer is calculated as 30.000000.
2013-11-06 16:01:13.212 MyMusicApp[43490:a0b] [Burstly]d t=2571i, m=0x19365210, AutoRefreshManager=0x19ef45b0, Timer is started
```

It seems like theres some AutoRefreshManager who randomly starts a timer and fetches an interstitial to display. I believe we dont request for this within our code. Anyone face this before or know why burstly behaves this way?

Here's a stack trace from the code

```
   0   MyMusicApp                      0x008ae9bb -[MMWebView initWithFrame:] + 75
1   MyMusicApp                      0x0087dc13 -[MMOverlayViewController init] + 691
2   MyMusicApp                      0x0087a8b9 +[MMInterstitial displayForApid:fromViewController:withOrientation:onCompletion:] + 1036
3   MyMusicApp                      0x00926411 -[BurstlyMillennialInterstitial presentInterstitial] + 400
4   MyMusicApp                      0x00926bcb -[Burstly_millennial_Adaptor showPrecachedAd] + 150
5   MyMusicApp                      0x00952ca7 -[OAIAdManager requestRefreshAd] + 1563
6   MyMusicApp                      0x00956173 -[OAIAutoRefreshManager requestRefreshAdToDelegate] + 42
7   Foundation                          0x03c04b67 __NSFireTimer + 97
8   CoreFoundation                      0x06370c46 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0637062d __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1181
10  CoreFoundation                      0x06358698 __CFRunLoopRun + 1816
11  CoreFoundation                      0x06357b33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
12  CoreFoundation                      0x0635794b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
13  GraphicsServices                    0x07cd49d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
14  GraphicsServices                    0x07cd47fe GSEventRun + 104
15  UIKit                               0x03fde94b UIApplicationMain + 1225
16  MyMusicApp                      0x0001bc5d main + 125
17  libdyld.dylib                       0x06d26725 start + 0
18  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
```

Any help/pointers will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at the Banner Refresh Rate in your "Creative Options" section on the interstitial.  We had those set and experienced a similar problem.  Turning them off fixed things for us.

Comment: Is this a configuration option on the burstly portal?

Comment: @tbag Yes. You need to expand the "Creative Options" panel on a given ad.

Comment: Yes figured that. Thanks for the help!